# Set empty attribute to polymer component inside another one

Tags: polymer

I've been trying to set an empty attribute to a polymer element inside another one.

This is the code for my custom element. What I'm trying to do is set "required" to the input element whenever custom-core-input's attribute required is true.

```
<polymer-element name="custom-core-input" attributes="columnId inputError validation required">
<template>
    <section>
        <paper-input-decorator id="decorator" error="{{inputError}}">
            <input id="custominput" is="core-input" validate="{{validation}}" on-change="{{inputCommited}}">
        </paper-input-decorator>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        inputCommited: function () {
            this.$.decorator.isInvalid = !this.$.custominput.validity.valid;
        }
    });
</script>
```

So far I've tried accessing the input element and set 'attr' from the script, I thought it wouldn't work, but was worth the try. I just have no idea about how to approach this, I feel like there must be an easy answer but cant think of it.

Also (and unrelated), I think I'm doing something else wrong, since the paper-input-decorator won't 'take' the inputError value.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Required` is a [conditional attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes), so you can set it on the `input` element like so:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-core-input" 
      attributes="columnId inputError validation required">
  <template>
    <section>
      <paper-input-decorator id="decorator"
            error="{{inputError}}"
            autovalidate>
        <input id="custominput" is="core-input"
              validate="{{validation}}"
              on-change="{{inputCommited}}"
              required?="{{required}}">
      </paper-input-decorator>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('custom-core-input', {
      required: false
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Note that the `required` attribute of `custom-core-input` must be initialized to false (or true, depending on your defaults).

The error message is only displayed if the input is invalid. So one option is to set the `autovalidate` attribute. Set `required` and `inputError` on your `custom-core-input` and you will see the error message on page load. More generally you want to set `isInvalid` to true or false depending on the current input validity.

Comment: What I wanted to avoid specifically was the autovalidate, since having a form-like control with almost all fields marked in red doesn't look ok. I want it to validate just after the input value is commited, I updated my question with the script. I will mark your answer as right since it solves the thread main question, but I'd appreciate it if you had any ideas on the "validation" side of this. Thanks :)

Comment: As to clarify, when I say that the error message is not being 'put' in the paper element I mean that, when inspecting the final code, it shows error="{{inputError}}", not with the value in it, as happens on any other attribute
I'm not expecting to see the error message just like that aside of validation.

Comment: You see `error="{{inputError}}"` because `error` is itself an attribute of a Polymer element (not an ordinary DOM element). In order for the property bindings to work correctly, this Polymer expression is not replaced with its result. The evaluation is deferred until this attribute is rendered in the `div.error-text` element inside the `paper-input-decorator`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, in the element prototype:

```
<script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function () {
                //check the "custom-core-input" required attribute:
                if (this.required)
                    //select the input element by Id, and set Required attr to True:
                    this.$.custominput.required = true;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I think I tried that before, is not working either, anyway. I'm thinking maybe the problem is not the required attr, but instead that I'm not managing properly the on-change event so that the decorator reacts to the validation. I'm updating the main post with what I've got on the script. Still, I don't seem to find the way to make the error attribute get its value properly.